# How to give emphasis to a positive verb in German?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In English we use "do" to emphasize a verb. For instance,

> A: Do you want to come with me?
>
> B: I do want to come with you, however ...

It is said in [Oxford Definitions](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1AVFA_enAZ782AZ782&sxsrf=ALeKk03p1Nb3gY7Pw2v2zAG3RMiN1y8dTQ%3A1604925840040&ei=kDmpX8XyAcmNlwSb6bDoAg&q=etwa+bedeutung&oq=etwa+bedeutung&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQyQMyAggAMgIIADIECAAQQzICCAAyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADIICC4QxwEQrwEyBAgAEAo6BwgjEOoCECc6CAgAEMkDEJECOgUIABCRAjoECCMQJzoECC4QQzoCCC46BwgAEMkDEENQivAYWL64QmDfukJoAnABeACAAboCiAGpCJIBBTItMy4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCsABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjF-tfUvvXsAhXJxoUKHZs0DC0Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) that as a particle, “etwa” has a similar meaning. For instance:

"Wenn er etwa doch noch kommt, dann soll er hier unterschreiben"

1. Which part of this phrase is equivalent of "do" with the previously mentioned meaning in the sentence above? (I am not totally sure if it is only "etwa" that creates that meaning or "etwa doch noch".)
2. Are there other ways to emphasize verbs in German?

Comment: We tend to use adverbs. For your specific example: "Natürlich möchte ich mit Dir mitkommen, aber ..." oder "Ich möchte wirklich mit Dir mitkommen, aber ...

Comment: Btw., you could translate the example almost literally: "Ich tue mit Dir mitkommen wollen, aber ..." This construction has fallen out of favor and is usually considered bad style.

Comment: I think many modal adverbs could serve this purpose, it's hard to be know which one to use without knowing more about the what the emphasis is meant to convey.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: @Roland: Also, it doesn't really convey emphasis. "Ich tue kochen." does not emphasize "kochen"; if anything, it simplifies the sentence structure to a point where only "tun" has to be conjugated (as some kind of pseudo-modal verb).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ["Die Verwendung des Wortes "tun" als Hilfsverb ist in bestimmten Fällen zulässig; zum Beispiel, um das eigentliche Verb zu betonen: "Rauchen tu ich schon lange nicht mehr", "Sterben tut jeder irgendwann einmal.""](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-es-macht-immer-tuut-tuut-a-390485.html)

Comment: @Roland: True, but note that those examples use "tun" as a workaround to allow for a different ordering of words, which I'd say is, in this case, what ultimately creates the emphasis. That's a different case than the "standard word order" found in your sentence "Ich tue mit dir mitkommen wollen."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German modal particles and adverbs are what you can use to emphasize verbs, but they are more differentiated than the use of "do" in English. It's hard to name a single one that you can use as a one-fits-all emphasis.

Your example:

> Wenn er etwa doch noch kommt, dann soll er hier unterschreiben

There are three modal particles here, and they all emphasize different aspects:

**etwa** -- reveals that the speaker tends to expect that "he" won't come -- the equivalent in English would be an emphasized "if", the use of subjunctive (Should he come, ...), or "do" + inf. ("If he does come, ...")

**doch** -- suggests that it was discussed before or seems evident to everyone that he probably won't come -- the English equivalent would be something like "though", but "do" + inf. could probably also express this.

**noch** -- implies that he could or should have been here by now but didn't show up so far. I think you could use "still" to say that in English.

So it could be translated as:

> If he does still come (though), he should sign here.

For a translation for the "do" + infinitive in your first example, there are also various possibilities depending on what you want to say. For example:

> B: I do want to come with you, however ...

> Ich will **schon** mir dir mitkommen, aber ... (emphasizes the contrast between wanting and not being able to)

> Ich will **gerne** mit dir mitkommen, aber ... (emphasizes the want)

In spoken language, it is also possible to put a heavy emphasis on "will" or on "mitkommen" to stress it:

> Ich ***will*** mit dir mitkommen, aber ...
> Ich will mit dir ***mitkommen***, aber ...

So the ways to emphasize are mostly modal particles, adverbs and spoken emphasis. Sometimes changing the order of words can also provide emphasis.

> Wollen wir heute abend etwas kochen oder lieber essen gehen? - Essen gehen möchte ich heute lieber.

Comment: There's also "ja", "wohl", "gar", and many more... welcome to the wonderful world of German modal particles :-)

Comment: Gutes Video zu Modalpartikeln https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Awhco_VHWE